# How can I warm lithium-ion batteries from a solar panel?

Tags: lithium-ion, heat, solar-energy, solar-charge-controller

I have a solar-powered system with a 12 V LiFePO4 battery which will need to operate in -20 to 60 °C conditions. I have a charge controller with a temperature sensor which will disable charging below 0 °C but on cold sunny days it would be better to direct the solar energy to a heating pad to enable charging.

My battery is 100 Ah and my solar panel is 50 W. A rough thermal calculation says 50 W of heating for less than 2 hours could raise the battery temperature by 20 °C.

Are there off-the-shelf control systems available which:

- Can be inserted between a solar charge controller and battery
- Won't discharge the battery to heat the battery (will only use any supplied charge current.)

Would such a control system really need to be fully integrated into the charge controller itself?

At a high level, what would be involved in designing such a system myself?

Comment: how much power are we talking here, both in expectable charging power in these clear-sky cold times as well as in terms of heat necessary to raise battery temperature by up to 20 °C?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I updated my question to include some estimates

Answer (score 1):

Your solar panel wattage is grossly undersized to maintain a 4S 100 AH LFP battery. The battery has roughly 1.3 kWh of energy. Your solar panel must be large enough to charge the discharge batteries fully in two days or less, 2- winter days when the Sun Hour drops to 2 or 3 hoursor less.

The second problem is that you would be in deficit charing in winter if you use a battery and solar panel to power a resistive heating element. A 50-watt element burning for two hours = 100 wh. Your undersized 50-watt solar panel cannot generate that much energy in winter, let alone fully recharge the battery.

If you want to make it work, get yourself a proper-sized solar panel and MPPT charge controller. Depending on the location, you would need a 200 to 300-watt solar panel and 20 to 25-amp MPPT controller. That might make enough heat to forget about a vampire heater load.

Comment: Why does my solar panel need to be able to fully charge the battery within 2 days? What's wrong if it takes longer, as long as I'm not in net deficit with my load?

Answer (score 0):

Go to your hardware store and get the heating tape that you place on roofs and rain gutters. It includes a thermostat that turns on the heating tape when it gets below freezing.

How to power it depends on the battery voltage. If you have a high voltage battery or a 48 V battery affects how to to power the heating tape.

Otherwise, get a heating pad of the same voltage as your battery voltage, and get a thermostat switch from Cantherm.

Wrap the battery with effective insulation: that will a) delay the need for heating and b) keep the heating within the battery (not wasted heating the air around it).

Comment: Wouldn't this discharge from the battery when it's cold but there's no sun?

Comment: Yes, it would. A 100 W heater would discharge a full, typical residential battery in 4 days. At that point, the BMS would protect the battery from over-discharge.

Answer (score 0):

(PARTIAL ANSWER)

The heater load should only be engaged when two binary conditions are satisfied:

1. current is flowing towards the battery (a charging condition), and
2. the temperature is below freezing.

Disable the thermal charging protection on the charge controller so that current may still flow to the battery in sub freezing temperatures.

For the 1st condition, a polarity-sensitive relay can be used as a switch to connect the heater load only when current is flowing towards the battery from the charge controller.

For the 2nd condition, a thermostat can be used to drive a 2nd relay when temperatures are below freezing.

The relays and connection to supply current should be arranged such that the heater load only gets power when both relays are closed.

NOTE:

- **care is required to ensure the connection of the heater load does not reverse the current direction, causing infinite switching of the 1st relay.**
- the power dissipated in relay coils may be significant and will reduce efficiency in warmer conditions